# JSF - Bean injection trouble

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets, postconstruct

As suggested by a user time ago in another question, I need to inject a bean in another bean.

So, i do the following :

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Articles {
    private String selectedMenu;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{user}")
    private UserManager user;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if(selectedMenu==null || selectedMenu.trim().isEmpty()) {
            this.selectedMenu="0";
        }
    }

    // now here i should access to user.methods

    // getter and setter
}
```

In fact, i can't access to UserManager data. I get these error :

**BROWSER** `malformedXML: INVALID_STATE_ERR: Dom Exception 11`

**SERVER LOG** 
`30-nov-2010 15.36.58 javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$ViewMap put
AVVERTENZA: Setting non-serializable attribute value into ViewMap: (key: profileSelector, value class: model.ProfileSelector)
30-nov-2010 15.36.59 com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager preProcessBean
GRAVE: JSF will be unable to create managed bean articles when it is requested.  The following problems where found:
     - Property user for managed bean articles does not exist.  Check that appropriate getter and/or setter methods exist.
30-nov-2010 15.36.59 com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit
GRAVE: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Unable to create managed bean articles.  The following problems were found:
     - Property user for managed bean articles does not exist.  Check that appropriate getter and/or setter methods exist.`

If i comment `@ManagedProperty(value="#{user}")` and `private UserManager user;` than i don't see any error. So that's the problem. What am I wrong?

Cheers

Comment: where do you see this error exactly ?

Comment: I see that error when i try to access to this bean!

Comment: @org meant *where*, not *when*. I.e. in the server logs, or in the webbrowser, or in the sky, etc

Comment: + post full error message along

Comment: Haha `in the sky` rocks!! I posted the error details in the topic :) Thanks people

Comment: I think it attempt `user` as `getUser` or `setUser`. In fact i need the instance of the bean UserManager (`@ManagedBean(name="user")`

Comment: Check updated answer compare it with your implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> malformedXML: INVALID_STATE_ERR: Dom Exception 11

This XML error indicates an error in your view (the XHTML), not in the bean. I don't understand why this error occurred, but likely you've a pretty complex component tree with several `rendered` attributes of which one is depending on the `user` property which caused a wrong state in the XML tree in the client side.

As to the server logs:

> AVVERTENZA: Setting **non-serializable** attribute value into ViewMap: (key: profileSelector, value **class: model.ProfileSelector**)

This does not necessarily harm, but to fix it, you need to let the class implement `java.io.Serializable`.

```
public class ProfileSelector implements Serializable {}
```

This way the server will be able to transfer the instance over network and/or store the instance on harddisk instead of in memory whenever necessary (when the server reboots or is placed in a server cluster).

---

> 30-nov-2010 15.36.59 com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager preProcessBean GRAVE: JSF will be unable to create managed bean articles when it is requested. The following problems where found: - **Property user for managed bean articles does not exist. Check that appropriate getter and/or setter methods exist**.

This is self-explaining as well. Ensure that there are proper getter/setter methods for the property `user` of the managed bean with name `articles`.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Articles {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{user}")
    private UserManager user;

    public UserManager getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserManager user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

You can if necessary let your IDE autogenerate them. In Eclipse, check the *Source* section in rightclick context menu (Alt+Shift+S).

---

> 30-nov-2010 15.36.59 com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit GRAVE: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Unable to create managed bean articles. The following problems were found: - **Property user for managed bean articles does not exist. Check that appropriate getter and/or setter methods exist**.

This has the same problem cause.

Comment: So, the inject property call a getter/setter. I meant it with "write the name of the bean instance".

Comment: I resolved 2 of these problem. The last still happen (`com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback`)

Comment: If you are certain that the proper getter/setter methods are added, then rebuild, redeploy and restart.

Comment: I've done it. I add the proper getter/setter to the UserManager bean (and, on postcostruct, i've write `this.user=this`, because it need to recognize the user instance when it return trought the getter), but i get the third error message. Also, now (by adding `implements Serializable`) i get some other further errors, like `Cannot serialize session attribute com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.LogicalViewMap for session 4B49A9591CAC0968C79EE88BD303533A
java.io.NotSerializableException: model.ProfileSelector`

Comment: Huh? `this.user = this`? This should have resulted in a compilation error. Are you adding the getter/setter to the `Articles` class?

Comment: Yeah but this should be due to the fact i debugged the application. In fact now it doesnt happen. Still the last error i don't understand why happen.

Comment: Yeah. I need to instantiate the user variable. I mean on `UserManager` bean. Also, what should it return on `public UserManager getUser() { return user; }` ? No, i didnt on Articles (why?)

Comment: The exception is telling that you need to add a getter and setter for `user` **on the `Articles` bean**! You don't need them in the `UserManager` bean at all. I expanded the code example.